# Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. When I debug it tells me: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: LocationChangeEvent. This is the code:

```
// imports
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// setup variables
var _stageWebView:StageWebView;
var myAdvertURL:String = "http://terrypaton.com/ads/exampleAdvert.html";
//
function createAd(event:MouseEvent):void {
    // check that _stageWebView doersn't exist
    if (! _stageWebView) {
        _stageWebView = new StageWebView () ;
        // set the size of the html 'window'
        _stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,480,80);
        // add a listener for when the content of the StageWebView changes
        _stageWebView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE,onLocationChange);
        // start loading the URL;
        _stageWebView.loadURL(myAdvertURL);
    }
    // show the ad by setting it's stage property;
    _stageWebView.stage = stage;
}
function toggleAd(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("toggling advert",_stageWebView);
    // check that StageWebView instance exists 
    if (_stageWebView) {
        trace("_stageWebView.stage:"+_stageWebView.stage);
        if (_stageWebView.stage == null) {
            //show the ad by setting the stage parameter
            _stageWebView.stage = stage;
        } else {
            // hide the ad by nulling the stage parameter
            _stageWebView.stage = null;
        }
    } else {
        // ad StageWebView doesn't exist - show create it
        createAd(null);
    }
}

function destroyAd(event:MouseEvent):void {
    // check that the instace of StageWebView exists
    if (_stageWebView) {
        trace("removing advert");
        // destroys the ad
        _stageWebView.stage = null;
        _stageWebView = null;
    }
}

function onLocationChange(event:LocationChangeEvent):void {
    // check that it's not our ad URL loading
    if (_stageWebView.location != myAdvertURL) {
        // destroy the ad as the user has kindly clicked on my ad
        destroyAd(null);
        // Launch a normal browser window with the captured  URL;
        navigateToURL( new URLRequest( event.location ) );
    }
}
// setup button listeners
createAdBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,createAd);
toggleAdBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleAd);
destroyAdBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,destroyAd);
```

Is there a way to change this code to make it work, or this code can't be used any longer?

Comment: I believe `LocationChangeEvent` is an AIR-specific class. Are you publishing as an AIR app, or to a SWF?

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference, LocationChangeEvent should indeed be in flash.events if compiled in AS3. I'm not sure why it's not found.

Try compiling a simpler example:

```
import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
var ev:LocationChangeEvent;
```

Comment: It is still not found for some reason

Comment: The reference says:

Language Version:  ActionScript 3.0
Runtime Versions:  AIR 2.5.

Try experimenting with the compiler settings. There must be an issue with some version mismatch.